# Is it in general wisest to not use member functions in control statements/functions, but rather store their value in a variable and then use that?

Tags: c++

I am creating a function that takes two sorted linked lists and merges them into a combined linked list. Here are my two implementations. Only the second one works in all cases I have tested. Left and right are the lists, front() returns the data in the node the head pointer points to, pushBack() adds a new node to the end of the list, and popFront() deletes the node at the front of the list. Merged is the new list they are combined into.

Implementation 1:

```
else {
    if ((left.front() = right.front())) {
      merged.pushBack(left.front());
      left.popFront();
      merged.pushBack(right.front());
      right.popFront();
    }
    else if (left.front() < right.front()) {
      merged.pushBack(left.front());
      left.popFront();
    }
    else {
      merged.pushBack(right.front());
      right.popFront();
    }
  }
```

Implementation 2:

```
else {
      int leftFront = left.front();
      int rightFront = right.front();
      
      if (leftFront == rightFront) {
        merged.pushBack(leftFront);
        left.popFront();
        merged.pushBack(rightFront);
        right.popFront();
      }
      else if (leftFront < rightFront) {
        merged.pushBack(leftFront);
        left.popFront();
      }
      else {
        merged.pushBack(rightFront);
        right.popFront();
      }
    }
```

It makes sense to me that I should not be using the member functions in control statements or as function arguments, since they are not static and might change during runtime, but I cannot see for the life of me why, in this particular situation I get different results.

In one test, with left = [1, 5, 10, 20] and right = [2, 4, 11, 19], the merge produces the list merged = [2, 2, 4, 4, 11, 11, 19, 19]. Obviously incorrect, but I don't see why it can't even get the first comparison correct. As far as I can tell, the else if is going to evaluate if 1 < 2, it is, and then push 1 to the back of merged, and then delete 1.

In the future I will follow implementation 2, as it seems safer to me, but I am confused why method 1 does not work in this situation

Comment: Did you mean to use `==` in the first one? You have `=`.

Comment: Compile and check the assembly.  Depending on what all `left` and `right` are and how well the compiler knows about it, the code could just get inlined which should yield the same performance.  Do double check by profiling both.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Thanks, that did it. I mistakenly believed that the assignment operator could be used like that for integers, in hindsight, obviously my code was setting left.front() = right.front() so the if statement's condition was 2=2, which is always true, so it adds both values to the list, which is why I only got duplicates, and only from the right list.